# Yesod/Persistent entity deriving Show

Tags: entity, persistent, yesod

In the [Persistent chapter of the Yesod book](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/persistent), an example is given where this entity

```
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes, TypeFamilies, GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving, TemplateHaskell, OverloadedStrings, GADTs #-}
import Database.Persist
import Database.Persist.TH
import Database.Persist.Sqlite
import Control.Monad.IO.Class (liftIO)

mkPersist sqlSettings [persist|
Person
    name String
    age Int
    deriving Show
|]
```

generates the code

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving, OverloadedStrings, GADTs #-}
import Database.Persist
import Database.Persist.Store
import Database.Persist.Sqlite
import Database.Persist.GenericSql.Raw (SqlBackend)
import Database.Persist.EntityDef
import Control.Monad.IO.Class (liftIO)
import Control.Applicative

data Person = Person
    { personName :: String
    , personAge :: Int
    }
  deriving (Show, Read, Eq)

type PersonId = Key Person

instance PersistEntity Person where
    -- A Generalized Algebraic Datatype (GADT).
    -- This gives us a type-safe approach to matching fields with
    -- their datatypes.
    data EntityField Person typ where
        PersonId   :: EntityField Person PersonId
        PersonName :: EntityField Person String
        PersonAge  :: EntityField Person Int

    type PersistEntityBackend Person = SqlBackend

    toPersistFields (Person name age) =
        [ SomePersistField name
        , SomePersistField age
        ]

    fromPersistValues [nameValue, ageValue] = Person
        <$> fromPersistValue nameValue
        <*> fromPersistValue ageValue
    fromPersistValues _ = Left "Invalid fromPersistValues input"

    -- Information on each field, used internally to generate SQL statements
    persistFieldDef PersonId = FieldDef
        (HaskellName "Id")
        (DBName "id")
        (FTTypeCon Nothing "PersonId")
        []
    persistFieldDef PersonName = FieldDef
        (HaskellName "name")
        (DBName "name")
        (FTTypeCon Nothing "String")
        []
    persistFieldDef PersonAge = FieldDef
        (HaskellName "age")
        (DBName "age")
        (FTTypeCon Nothing "Int")
        []
```

Why does adding `deriving Show` to the Person entity generate the derivation of all three typeclasses `(Show, Read, Eq)`? I'm very new to Haskell and Yesod, so I apologize if it's obvious, but I can't find the answer anywhere! Is it just an error in the documentation? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy: it's a typo in the book :). If you look at the actual generated code (with `-ddump-splices`), you'll see that it's only actually deriving the `Show` instance.

Comment: It seems like it would be worthwhile to fix the book. It's still like this on version 1.4.

Comment: Thank you, I thought I'd made that fix but apparently not. It's up to date now.