# Store existing data-type with Yesod's Persistent

Tags: haskell, yesod, persistent

All the tutorials and references that I could find about Persistent describe in great detail how Persistent can automatically create a new data-type, schema, migration, etc. out of a single definition in its DSL. However, I couldn't find an explanation on how to get Persistent to handle already existing data-types.

**An example:** Suppose I have an already existing Haskell module for some game logic. It includes a record type for a player. (It's meant to be used through lenses, hence the underscores.)

```
data Player = Player { _name   :: String
                     , _points :: Int
                     -- more fields ...
                     }
$(makeLenses ''Player)
```

**Question:** What's the canonical way to store such a type in a data-base with Persistent? Is there some type-class that I can implement. Or should I best define a new type through Persistent, e.g.

```
share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"] [persistLowerCase|
PlayerEntry
    name Text
    points Int
|]
```

and then manually map between these types?

```
playerToEntry :: Player -> PlayerEntry
playerToEntry pl = PlayerEntry (pl^.name) (pl^.points)

entryToPlayer :: PlayerEntry -> Player
entryToPlayer e = Player (name e) (points e)
```

Comment: Do you think it would make sense just to manually define the fields like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14097615/439699)?

Comment: @ace Sure, you could manually generate all the code which `mkPersist` generates for you. I posted this question originally, because I didn't find a place where it was well documented how to do that. However, as it turned out I actually needed extra columns in the table anyway. So, marshalling between two types turned out to be a good solution in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution to this problem was to add a new type through Yesod's `mkPersist`, and manually marshal between those.

`config/models`:

```
PlayerEntry
    name Text
    points Int
    created UTCTime default=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

`Marshalling.hs`:

```
fromPlayerEntry :: PlayerEntry -> Player
fromPlayerEntry PlayerEntry {..} = Player { name = playerName
                                          , points = playerPoints
                                          }

createPlayerEntry :: Text -> YesodDB App (Entity PlayerEntry)
createPlayerEntry name = do
    currentTime <- liftIO getCurrentTime
    let player = PlayerEntry { playerName = name
                             , playerPoints = 0
                             , playerCreated = currentTime
                             }
    playerId <- insert player
    return $ Entity playerId player

updatePlayerEntry :: PlayerEntryId -> Player -> YesodDB App ()
updatePlayerEntry playerId Player {..} =
    update playerId [ PlayerName =. name
                    , PlayerPoints =. points
                    ]
```

One possible advantage is that you can have fields in your table, that are not required in the internal record. In my example, it was useful to attach a creation date to the player. However, this was only used in the web-interface layer, it was never used in the internal game logic, which defined the `Player` type. However, due to the manual marshalling I could add that field to the same database table nonetheless.

Answer (score 3):

From: http://www.yesodweb.com/book/persistent

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
module Employment where

import Database.Persist.TH

data Employment = Employed | Unemployed | Retired
    deriving (Show, Read, Eq)
derivePersistField "Employment"
```

The `derivePersistField` function is the template Haskell magic that makes it work.

Note, you need to do the `derivePersistField` thing in a separate file to where you do the `mkPersist` to avoid a TH phase error.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, that's not exactly what I'm looking for. `derivePersistField` will generate a type for a *column* of a table. However, I need a type for a *whole table*. The way I solved it in my case was to generate a new type like `PlayerEntry` above and then manually marshal between `Player` and `PlayerEntry`. For some of the fields within my type I used `derivePersistField` to generate the corresponding columns. I guess I should write this up in an answer here.

Comment: I would like to see how you did it @Lemming.  I'm also trying to find a good solution for this issue and strongly considering moving away from persistent because of this.

Comment: @ace As requested, I added my solution.